# Magento background cannot display uploaded pictures

Tags: magento2, magento-admin

I use magento2.4.6, and the catalog/Categories in the background cannot display the pictures I uploaded
[image]

And the following error is displayed:
[image]

```
jquery.js:4050 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientWidth') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientWidth')
    at UiClass.setLayoutStyles (https://www.instar.ro/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/grid/masonry.js:133:58)
    at UiClass.initComponent (https://www.instar.ro/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/grid/masonry.js:104:18)
    at setNested (https://www.instar.ro/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/utils/objects.js:44:25)
    at Object.nested (https://www.instar.ro/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/utils/objects.js:118:20)
    at UiClass.set (https://www.instar.ro/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/element/element.js:305:19)
    at updateValue (https://www.instar.ro/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/element/links.js:80:19)
    at Function.notifySubscribers (https://www.instar.ro/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:1401:50)
    at Function.valueHasMutated (https://www.instar.ro/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:1645:46)
    at UiClass.observable (https://www.instar.ro/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:1609:40)
    at setNested (https://www.instar.ro/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/utils/objects.js:44:25) undefined
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue,
I had this issue occurring too. i managed to fixed this one by updating Google Chrome version to latest version(!), or even try to use other browser such as Firefox